# NSFetchedResultController cached results won't disappear

Tags: ios, swift, azure

I have a NSFetchedResultsController which was taken from an azure example. It works well and fetches data from the database correctly, but if I exit the application, and delete records from the database, they still show up in my application, and there's no way to make them disappear without reinstalling the application. Does anyone have any idea what could cause this? I don't have a cache set, and I've tried setting one and deleting it on startup, but it has not worked. Here's the code for the fetchedResultController.

```
lazy var fetchedResultController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> = {
    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Events")
    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!

    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "completed != true")
    //fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "text != ''")

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: true)]

    let resultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    resultsController.delegate = self;

    return resultsController
}()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. The problem was with a MSSyncTable. Now I perform a forced purge on the table every time I refresh, and this keeps the values correct.

```
self.table?.forcePurge(completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the config that you show I definitely can tell that it is not connected with Cache of the `NSFetchedResultsController`. Becouse you do not set Cache name in the constructor method.

From Apple documentation.

> When you initialize an instance of NSFetchedResultsController, you
>   typically specify a cache name. (If you do not specify a cache name,
>   the controller does not cache data.)

Probably you're database is not fetching update properly from the server.

Comment: But the records are definitely stored on the device, because I can still access the records I've previously seen, when starting the app with no internet connection. I've also tried passing nil to the function for deleting cache, but there was no difference.